# What is $(\cal I,I$ $X)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation, modules, ideals

I read Algebras, Rings and Modules by Hazewinkel and I don't understand what is $(\cal I,I$$X)$. Could you please tell me the meaning of this denotation?

[image]

Comment: I believe it is the sum of the ideals $\cal I$ and $\cal{I} X$.